# Assertion error failing - can't find a reason - Norvig Sudoku

Tags: python

I'm working through Peter Norvig's Sudoku solver program and I'm having trouble with the following line:

```
assert peers['C2'] == (['A2', 'B2', 'D2', 'E2', 'F2', 'G2', 'H2', 'I2',
                        'C1', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9',
                        'A1', 'A3', 'B1', 'B3'])
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Sudoku.py", line 56, in <module>
    test()
  File "Sudoku.py", line 33, in test
    'A1', 'A3', 'B1', 'B3'])
AssertionError
```

I tried debugging with the following code but no differences show up...

```
pprint(peers['C2'])
peersc2 = ['A2', 'B2', 'D2', 'E2', 'F2', 'G2', 'H2', 'I2', 'C1', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'A1', 'A3', 'B1', 'B3']
print(list(set(peersc2) - set(peers['C2'])))
```

Here's the code:

```
# http://norvig.com/sudoku.html

# from pprint import pprint

# concatenates letter and number to create cell
def cross(A, B):
    return [a + b for a in A for b in B]


def test():
    # 9 rows and 9 cols
    assert len(squares) == 81
    # row, col, and 9x9 square
    assert len(unitlist) == 27
    # each square 3 x 3
    assert all(len(units[s]) == 3 for s in squares)
    # row + col + square - repeats
    assert all(len(peers[s]) == 20 for s in squares)
    # should be row, column, and square for cell
    assert units['C2'] == [['A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2', 'E2', 'F2', 'G2', 'H2', 'I2'],
                           ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9'],
                           ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3']]

    # Next assertion fails
    # pprint(peers['C2'])
    # peersc2 = ['A2', 'B2', 'D2', 'E2', 'F2', 'G2', 'H2', 'I2', 'C1', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'A1',
    #            'A3', 'B1', 'B3']
    # print(list(set(peersc2) - set(peers['C2'])))

    # should be row, column, and square without repeats
    assert peers['C2'] == (['A2', 'B2', 'D2', 'E2', 'F2', 'G2', 'H2', 'I2',
                            'C1', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9',
                            'A1', 'A3', 'B1', 'B3'])


digits = '123456789'
rows = 'ABCDEFGHI'
cols = digits
# makes each square
squares = cross(rows, cols)

# Creates arrays with each row 'A1', 'B1', 'C1', etc.
unitlist = ([cross(rows, c) for c in cols] +
            [cross(r, cols) for r in rows] +
            [cross(rs, cs) for rs in ('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI') for cs in
             ('123', '456', '789')])
# assigns cell to all associated rows, columns, and squares
# ex) I5 > A5-I5 + I1-I9 + G4-G6, H4-H6, I4-I6
units = dict((s, [u for u in unitlist if s in u])
             for s in squares)
# creates the row and col pairs for each cell
# A1 = A1-I1 + A1-A9 + A1-A3, B1-B3, C1-C3
peers = dict((s, set(sum(units[s], [])) - set([s]))
             for s in squares)

test()
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What *is* `peers['C2']` at that point?

Comment: `peers['C2']` is a **set**, not a list.

Comment: You appear to have copied the code from that link incorrectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `peers` maps strings to [*sets*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets),and not to lists, you can cast `set()` to the list:

As you can see, if we call your code in the python shell:

```
>>> peers['C2']
set(['F2', 'G2', 'H2', 'D2', 'I2', 'C9', 'C6', 'A1', 'A3', 'C8', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'C3', 'C1', 'E2', 'C7', 'A2', 'C5', 'C4'])
>>>
```

Therefore, you need to assert to a [**set**](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

```
# http://norvig.com/sudoku.html

# from pprint import pprint

# concatenates letter and number to create cell
def cross(A, B):
    return [a + b for a in A for b in B]


def test():
    # 9 rows and 9 cols
    assert len(squares) == 81
    # row, col, and 9x9 square
    assert len(unitlist) == 27
    # each square 3 x 3
    assert all(len(units[s]) == 3 for s in squares)
    # row + col + square - repeats
    assert all(len(peers[s]) == 20 for s in squares)
    # should be row, column, and square for cell
    assert units['C2'] == [['A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2', 'E2', 'F2', 'G2', 'H2', 'I2'],
                           ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9'],
                           ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3']]

    # Next assertion fails
    # pprint(peers['C2'])
    # peersc2 = ['A2', 'B2', 'D2', 'E2', 'F2', 'G2', 'H2', 'I2', 'C1', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'A1',
    #            'A3', 'B1', 'B3']
    # print(list(set(peersc2) - set(peers['C2'])))

    # should be row, column, and square without repeats
    assert peers['C2'] == set(['A2', 'B2', 'D2', 'E2', 'F2', 'G2', 'H2', 'I2',
                            'C1', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9',
                            'A1', 'A3', 'B1', 'B3'])


digits = '123456789'
rows = 'ABCDEFGHI'
cols = digits
# makes each square
squares = cross(rows, cols)

# Creates arrays with each row 'A1', 'B1', 'C1', etc.
unitlist = ([cross(rows, c) for c in cols] +
            [cross(r, cols) for r in rows] +
            [cross(rs, cs) for rs in ('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI') for cs in
             ('123', '456', '789')])
# assigns cell to all associated rows, columns, and squares
# ex) I5 > A5-I5 + I1-I9 + G4-G6, H4-H6, I4-I6
units = dict((s, [u for u in unitlist if s in u])
             for s in squares)
# creates the row and col pairs for each cell
# A1 = A1-I1 + A1-A9 + A1-A3, B1-B3, C1-C3
peers = dict((s, set(sum(units[s], [])) - set([s]))
             for s in squares)

test()
```

Then if we run your program:

```
bash-3.2$ python sudokusolver.py
bash-3.2$
```

An no errors are triggered!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

`peers` is a dictionary mapping strings to **sets**, not to a lists.

Sets and lists are never equal even if they have the same contents. Assert you have a set instead:

```
assert peers['C2'] == set(['A2', 'B2', 'D2', 'E2', 'F2', 'G2', 'H2', 'I2',
                           'C1', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9',
                           'A1', 'A3', 'B1', 'B3'])
```

and the assertion passes.

If you look at the [original](http://norvig.com/sudoku.html) you'll see that's exactly what the original code does.

Comment: O man, missed that one little word... Thanks!